# Problem showing fields in grid channel fields

Tags: error, grid, channel-fields

I have a strange problem and I think there is a bug in the platform (v2.9.2 - Build Date: 20141004 ), related to Grid field.

I'm trying to access more fields and one of this fields need to be accessed many times in the template for example:

```
{grid_name search:field_used_for_search="criteria"} 
  something 
  {grid_name:field1} ........
  {grid_name:field1}........
  {grid_name:field1}......
  {grid_name:field2}.........
  {grid_name:other_field}.........
  {grid_name:field3 status="Active"}
    {grid_name:field3:count}
    ...... 
  {/grid_name:field3}
  {grid_name:field1}
{/grid_name}
```

I added two new fields in channel fields for this Grid, because I need to add a new feature in website and when I tried to access those new fields I had a big surprise, the page displayed something like:

```
{grid_name search:field_used_for_search="criteria"} 
  {grid_name:field3 status="Active"}

  {/grid_name:field3}
{/grid_name}
```

Let's presume that I want to to show a field (doesn't matter if is one of those added recently or olds) somewhere inside **grid_name** tag. I thought maybe is something with my new fields and I tried to access others (old ones) and is the same behavior. So I deleted some of the old recurrence from my template and I access other one and surprise, works.

The way that I access those fields is right. So if I delete for example two recurrence of {grid_name:field2} I can access those two fields added recently, but if I keep the old ones and I try to display all of them I get the previous error.

Do you have some suggestions ?

PS: The template is very large (320 full lines, without white lines), can be a problem related to this ?

Thanks,
Bobo

Answer (score 0):

Possibly fixed in next EE version 2.9.3?:

> Fixed a bug (#20704) where Grid tags may not parse correctly if
>   multiple Grid tag pairs are present and one tag pair contains no
>   variables.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/about/changelog.html#version-2-9-3